# Online radio stream on slider revolution

Tags: html, slider, revolution-slider, internet-radio

I have a html code for my radio streaming web player from radio.co but I can't embed it on slider revolution. Audio layer doesn't have streaming option and if I copy the code as a text layer it won't show on the screen.

So what's the correct way to do this?

Edit : This is the HTML code.

```
<script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/070d154.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the embed code from the streaming Web player?

Comment: I included the code. Thanks.